# How to apply order by to linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

In c# linq, I have this code which works

```
    private IQueryable<v_CompanyInquiryInfo> SearchCompany(string pCompanyName)
    {
        var mCompany = from d in db.v_CompanyInquiryInfo
                       where d.CompanyName.ToLower().Equals(pCompanyName)
                       select ((v_CompanyInquiryInfo)d);
        return mCompany;
    }
```

And I have this

```
    private IQueryable SearchCompanies(string pValues)
    {
        string mValues = pValues;
        foreach (string lWord in iRestrictedWords)
        {
            mValues.Replace(lWord, "");
        }
        var mSearchArray = pValues.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var mCompanyCriteria = db.v_CompanyInquiryInfo.AsExpandable().Where(TradingInquiryController.CompanyContainsSearchTerms(mSearchArray));
        var mCompanies = mCompanyCriteria
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.CompanyName,
            x.CompanyID,
            x.SearchTags,
            Rank = mSearchArray.Sum(s => ((x.SearchTags.Length - x.SearchTags.Replace(s, "").Length) / s.Length))
        });

        var mResults =  mCompanies.OrderByDescending(o => o.Rank).Skip(0).Take(20);
        return mResults;
    }
```

which also works. However I want the return type of this second function to be `IQueryable<v_CompanyInquiryInfo>`. The problem is there is a `Rank` new dynamic column added, and then I sort by it. How can I apply the same ordering but without creating a new column for it, then apply a cast to `v_CompanyInquiryInfo`. So that I can return `IQueryable<v_CompanyInquiryInfo>`. I can't figure out the syntax for this. Also it can return all columns.

Thanks

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand your code. Please remove the parts that are not relevant.

Comment: You can cast from one object type to another. You can project using `Select`. You don't need to create a new field just for sorting. What is the purpose of `Skip(0)`? We need to see the definition of `v_CompanyInquiryInfo` to know how to project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create that property:

```
private IQueryable SearchCompanies(string pValues)
    {
        string mValues = pValues;
        foreach (string lWord in iRestrictedWords)
        {
            mValues.Replace(lWord, "");
        }
        var mSearchArray = pValues.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var mCompanyCriteria = db.v_CompanyInquiryInfo.AsExpandable().Where(TradingInquiryController.CompanyContainsSearchTerms(mSearchArray));

        var mCompanies = mCompanyCriteria        
.OrderByDescending(x => mSearchArray.Sum(s => ((x.SearchTags.Length - x.SearchTags.Replace(s, "").Length) / s.Length))
;

        //var mResults =  mCompanies.Skip(0).Take(20);
        return mCompanies;
    }
```